# Ćuk converter implementation

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, opto-isolator, 555, converter

I am trying to design a 50 W non-isolated Ćuk converter. I am using the IRF540N MOSFET which is driven by a 555 timer-TLP250 setup, using the fast-recovery BY399P diode.

I am trying to find a design procedure for selection of the inductors and capacitors. The input current is 1-2 A operating in a range of 12-30 V.

The regular design procedure which involves finding the values from duty cycle and ripple percentages (current ripple = 20%) seems to give a proper voltage waveform in simulation but is extremely inefficient (10%). Is there a different design procedure that can be applied to rectify this?

**Schematic:**
[image: Simulink model]
The 555 subsystem in the above image is modelled using:
[image: 555 circuit]

I have connected the output of the 555 timer to a TLP250 which drives the MOSFET. The TLP250's supply is taken from a separate transformer.

Comment: Your main circuit is sadly lacking in values.

Comment: @Andyaka: Have added the values, sorry for the error.

Comment: Output voltage? Coupling between coils (if any)? Input voltage range? Capacitor values? MOSFET type?

Comment: The resistances used in your 555 circuit are *far* too low, you're going to be wasting tons of power. A 555 already wastes far too much power alone, you don't need to make it worse!

Comment: @Andyaka: No coupling between coils. Input range is between 12-30 V. I have indicated the capacitor values in the image. Output voltage that I got by simulation (input = 17 V) for these set of values was 24.38 V. MOSFET type is IRF540N.

Comment: @Hearth I actually changed the values of R2 and R3 in the Proteus schematic to 1.5k, apologize for not including it, I have edited the image to reflect the same!

Comment: Are you driving the IRF540 correctly? You'll want at least about 10 V on the gate to turn it on. What's your operating frequency? What does the gate waveform on the FET look like? Are you using inductor models that simulate saturation, and if so, what's the rated saturation current compared to the peak current through them?

Comment: You are aware that the Cuk converter produces a negative voltage output?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, didn't include the negative sign.

Comment: @Hearth I am driving it using the TLP250 which outputs about 20V. Operating frequency is 3.7 kHz. The gate waveform looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/06qdzvt 
I am not using inductor models that simulate saturation, I don't know whether it is possible to do it in Simulink.

Comment: 3.7 kHz feels very low for a switching converter, but I've never worked with Ćuk converters. 20 V is too high for an IRF540; the simulation model probably doesn't care but a real one would risk being destroyed by 20 V on the gate--you should generally stay at least a few volts away from the absolute maximum listed on the datasheet.

Comment: vgs is a constant value in that picture. State what the peak value is and what the trough value is. State rise times and fall times please.